# Overriding html and css to modify day cell on a month calendar with jquery fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to modify jquery full calendar's day cell.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naLb7v17/27/)

I want to edit the css and html in the day cell of the month to show something like this, where the event covers the entire day cell preventing any new dayclick event from occurring. I want max 1 event per day!

[image]

I've tried to use the eventRender callback to set some html and css but I haven't had any luck, here is what I tried.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                //defaultDate: '2016-12-17',
                //defaultView: 'basicWeek',
                //height: 300,
                //eventColor: 'green',
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'event',
                        start: '2016-12-17T12:00:00',
                        duration: '60 min'
                        //rendering: 'background'
                    }
                ],
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    element.html('');
                    var new_description =
                        + '<div style="text-align: center; height=100%; width=100%;">'
                        +  moment(event.start._i).format("HH:mm") + '<br/>'
                        + event.duration + '<br/>'
                        + event.title
                        + '</div>'
                        ;
                    element.append(new_description);
                }
            });
```

And here is what is looks like. You'll notice there is some white space on the top where the user can click it and a day event will be triggered and the text isn't center aligned

[image]

Quick question - should I avoid fullcalendar and learn react js with the https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates plugin??? It seems like I could have complete control over the html and css for each cell!

Answer (score 1):

To override CSS properties of *fullcalender*, make sure your custom CSS comes after your **`fullcalendar.css`** declaration.

Using **`eventRender`** callback, find below, a working snippet illustrating the approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.html('');
            element.append(
                moment(event.start._i).format("h:mm a") + '<br/>'
                + event.duration + '<br/>'
                + event.title
            );
            var eventDay = $(".fc-day");

            $.each( eventDay, function( key, value ) {
                if ( value.dataset["date"] == moment(event.start._i).format("YYYY-MM-DD") ) {
                    value.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            });
        },
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Event Name',
                start: '2016-12-19T14:00:00',
                duration: '60 min',
                color: 'transparent'
            }
        ],
        dayClick: function() {
            return null;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<style type='text/css'>
    .fc-event-container {
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .fc-event {
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .fc-day-grid-event {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

*Please note: [version 3.1.0](https://fullcalendar.io/download/) of [**`fullcalendar`**](https://fullcalendar.io) was used for the purpose of this illustration; I've realised that you were using a quite older one (version 1.5.3) and don't mind updating that.*

*Equally added [**`moment.js`**](http://momentjs.com/) as necessary to handling dates effectively.*

*Read more on Moment Parsing (String Format) [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).*

Comment: I'm having an issue with this answer. When I click on the event in the day cell, it triggers a dayClick, not an eventClick.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact opposite of this. I want event click to occur anywhere on the cell that has an event. Hence the event spanning the entire width and height of the day cell.

Comment: @user1186050: Have just updated my post so as to prevent day click events from occurring as you've stated.

Comment: NO, please read the original post. I don't want the dayclick callback disabled! I still need it for creating events when the day is clicked, what I want is the event to span over the entire day cell, so that once an event is created, the day cell isn't clickable anymore ( it's covered by the event) preventing more then one event from being created!

Comment: @user1186050: You should please consider updating your post as it isn't clear enough; my answer is based on the understanding I've derived from your initial post and comment above. The main topic as you pointed out in the title of your post is about overriding HTML and CSS outputs. That will enable me and or other ones to possibly assist you addressing the challenge you are currently facing in a more effective manner.

Comment: You got downvoted because you didn't ansewr the question. In my question I'm pretty specific "I want to edit the css and html in the day cell of the month to show something like this, where the event covers the entire day cell preventing any new dayclick event from occurring. I want max 1 event per day!" What you have done is close but not correct and you then edited your answer to return false if the day click is called. This isn't what I originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same if *calendar cell background color is exactly same as the event on that cell* and also you can *restrict to add event on calendar if already one event for that calendar cell is there*. Below is a sample example to achieve it.

```
        var h = {};

        if ($('#calendar').width() <= 400) {
            $('#calendar').addClass("mobile");
            h = {
                left: 'title, prev, next',
                center: '',
                right: 'today,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            };
        } else {
            $('#calendar').removeClass("mobile");
            if (App.isRTL()) {
                h = {
                    right: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    left: 'prev,next,month'
                };
            } else {
                h = {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'prev,next,month'
                };
            }
        }

var events = [
                {
                   title: 'event1',
                   start: '2016-12-17T12:00:00',
                   duration: '60 min',
                   backgroundColor: '#BFCAD1'
                },
                {
                   title: 'event2',
                   start: '2016-12-24T12:00:00',
                   duration: '30 min',
                   backgroundColor: '#BFCAD1'
                }
             ]

function handleCalendarDateClicked() {
     var tempEvent = {};                       
     tempEvent.title = "event3";
     tempEvent.start = '2016-12-31T12:00:00';
     tempEvent.duration = '30 min';
     tempEvent.backgroundColor = '#BFCAD1';
     events.push(tempEvent);
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents'); //to avoid event duplicates
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events); // to reinitialize calendar with updated events array
} 

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                disableDragging: false,
                header: h,
                editable: false,
                events: events,
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    element.html('');
                    var new_description =
                        + '<div style="text-align: center; height=100%; width=100%;">'
                        +  moment(event.start._i).format("HH:mm") + '<br/>'
                        + event.duration + '<br/>'
                        + event.title
                        + '</div>'
                        ;
                    element.append(new_description);
                },
                dayRender: function(date, cell) {
                   //based on condition like for the date event is there you can set background color of that cell 
                   var cellDate = date.format('MMM DD, YYYY');
                   if (dayRenderDates && dayRenderDates.indexOf(cellDate) > -1) {
                      cell.css("background-color", "#BFCAD1");
                   }
                },
                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                   //here, you can add event based on some condition like you want if there is already an event attached to the cell then another cannot be added
                   var newDate = new Date(date.format());
                   return ((dayRenderDates.indexOf(newDate) > -1) ? '' : handleCalendarDateClicked(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
                }
            });
```

- **dayRenderDates** is an array of dates for which event is there
- **handleCalendarDateClicked()** is a function called to add an event

Answer (score 1):

This might be a getto way of trying to make this work.

The HTML:

```html
<div id="calendarContainer" style="border:solid 2px red;">
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

Tha javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      var eventHeight = ($("#calendarContainer").height() / 6) - 20,
        eventWidth = ($("#calendarContainer").width() / 7) - 6;
      var new_description = '<div style="text-align:center;position:absolute;top:-19px;left:-1px;background-color:#3366cc;height:' + eventHeight + 'px;width:' + eventWidth + 'px;border-radius:5px;padding-top:3px;padding-left:4px;"> <div>event <br> time <br> title</div> </div>';
      element.append(new_description);
    },




    events: [{
      title: 'event',
      start: '2016-12-17T12:00:00',
      duration: '60 min'
        //rendering: 'background'
    }]


  });

  // console.log($('#calendar').html());



});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your jquery as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'month',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
            var new_description =
                '<div style="text-align:center">3PM' + '<br/>' +
                '60min' + '<br/>' +
                'title</div>'
            ;
            element.append(new_description);
        },

        events: [{
            title: 'event',
            start: '2016-12-17T12:00:00',
            duration: '60 min'
                //rendering: 'background'
        }]

    });

    // console.log($('#calendar').html());

    // button click
});
```